# Matrices Java y matrices

Tags: java, matrices

Tengo otro ejercicio en el que estoy atascado. Pienso que como lo resolví debería estar bien pero no sale. Debe ser algo que pasé por alto.
El enunciado es este: "Una casa de comida rápida utiliza una matriz de 20 filas y 5 columnas para determinar cada plato del menú y sus correspondientes ingredientes que contiene. Para ello, cada fila representa un plato principal en donde en la primera columna se especifica su nombre (por ejemplo: Milanesa), y en las demás los posibles acompañamientos que puede tener el plato (por ejemplo, puré, ensalada rusa, papas fritas, ensalada de lechuga y tomate, ensalada de zanahoria, etc). En caso de que tenga el plato menos de 4 tipos de acompañamiento, en la matriz se cargará la palabra Ninguno en las posiciones que queden vacías."
Lo hice con una matriz de 3 x 3 para probar (supongo que si funciona en una así funciona en la de 20 x 5).

```
        String menu[][] = new String[3][3]; //creo la matriz
        
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);//creo el scanner
        
//hago el bucle para ingresar el menú y sus acompañamientos
        
        for(int f = 0; f < 3;f++){
            System.out.println("ingresa el nombre del plato: ");
            menu[f][0] = teclado.next();
            for(int c = 1; c < 3; c++){
                System.out.println("ingresa un acompañamiento (si no tiene ingresa \"Ninguno\")");
                
                    menu[f][c] = teclado.next();
                }
            }
        
        Scanner teclado2 = new Scanner(System.in);/*creo un nuevo scanner 
        para un nuevo ingreso por teclado*/
        String seleccion;//creo una variable para guardar la selección de menú
        
//pido ingresar un menú entre los que hay       
        System.out.println("ingresa un menu de los siguientes:");
        System.out.println(menu[0][0]);
        System.out.println(menu[1][0]);
        System.out.println(menu[2][0]);
      
        
        seleccion= teclado2.next(); //guardo el ingreso por teclado en mi variable
        
/*Hago el bucle que comparará el ingreso por teclado con la primera columan de cada fila
y debe devolver el las restantes columanas de dicha fila*/
        for(int f = 0; f < 3;f++){
           if(seleccion == menu[f][0]){ 
            for(int c = 1; c < 3; c++){
               
                    System.out.println("se acompaña con : " + menu[f][c]); 
                }  
            }
           else{
               System.out.println("No tenemos ese plato");
           }
        }
```

Por alguna razón que no alcanzo a comprender mi sentecia "if" no me da True aunque el ingreso por teclado sea correcto.
Alguna idea de lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: si ingresas pollo a ala brasa ,usando `next` capturara el dato solo hasta el espacio es decir solo pollo ,mejor usa `nextLine()` ,no necesitas dos `scanner` basta con uno y por ultimo para comparar datos String usa `equals` y no `==` ...  `if(seleccion.equals(menu[f][0]))`

Comment: Hola. Entendido, voy tomando notas sobre lo de el next y no usar el == para comparar los string. Son cosas que no sabía. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo que debes considerar con los bucles es que estos recorren todo el array y evalúan 1 x 1 las condicionales suponiendo que en la ultima posición guardaste pollo
`menu[2][0]= pollo` al iterar `menu[0][0]` ahi no aplicara tu condicional `if` pasara a `else` e imprimirá el mensaje que tienes ahi lo mismo en `menu[1][0]` volverá a imprimir el mensaje y recién cuando sea `menu[2][0]` imprimirá los acompañantes,entonces para evitar usar el mensaje repetido podes usar un boolean que  cambie su valor de `false` a `true` cuando no se encuentre el plato buscado. y de esa manera si no hay coincidencia te devuelva un solo mensaje

```
   boolean verificar=false;
        for(int f = 0; f < 3;f++){
           if(seleccion .equals(menu[f][0])){ 
            for(int c = 1; c < 3; c++){
               System.out.println("se acompaña con : " + menu[f][c]); 
               verificar=true;
              } 
            }  
        }
        if(!verificar){System.out.println("No tenemos ese plato");}
```

Comment: Bien. Entiendo por qué no funcionaba la manera en la que lo hice. El bucle comparaba  todos los platos y como no todos eran el seleccionado daba false (¿puede ser?) Puse en práctica todo lo que me señalaste y funciona de 10. Pero todavía doy vueltas al asunto, no termino de entender por qué al hacerlo así funciona.

Comment: para empezar siempre te daba false por que usabas == en vez de equals, [info](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/comparando-java-vs-equals/) partiendo de esa premisa si hubieras usado equals si te hubiera funcionado la condicional pero habia un detalle extra y es que en todas las iteraciones no ibas a conseguir un true que imprimiese los acompañantes quiza en la segunda o tercer iteracion pero que hay de las demas ,siempre hubieras conseguido caer en else y hubieras imprimido el mensaje de "no tenemos ese plato" tantas veces como el tamaño del array - la iteracion donde aplica el if

Comment: ¡Aaaaaaaah! Ahora entiendo (nadie en el curso me dijo lo de equals por eso usaba == para comparar) lo otro me doy cuenta que la ultima sentencia debe quedar fuera del bucle... Bueno, es que estoy aprendiendo :) Muchisimas gracias te debo una birra.